# How to resolve dependency conflict while installing @ngx-translate/core in Angular app with PrimeNG template Diamond?

Tags: angular, primeng, ngx-translate

npm install @ngx-translate/core error in angular application

I have angular application with PrimeNg template Diamond and I want to install @ngx-translate/core.
When I run it, it shows the following error in terminal:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: diamond-ng@15.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=16.0.0" from @ngx-translate/core@15.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngx-translate/core
npm ERR!   @ngx-translate/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Can someone please help me?

Also, here is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "diamond-ng",
    "version": "15.1.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
        "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.0.3",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.0.3",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.0.3",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.0.3",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.0.3",
        "chart.js": "^3.3.2",
        "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
        "primeicons": "6.0.1",
        "primeng": "15.2.0",
        "prismjs": "1.9.0",
        "quill": "^1.3.7",
        "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "tslib": "^2.5.2",
        "typescript": "~4.9.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried  npm install @ngx-translate/core --force ?

Comment: It's very risky and considered bad practice... @user1075296

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version of `@angular/common` you're using in your project doesn't satisfy the dependency requirements of the package `@ngx-translate/core`.

You're using `@angular/common` version `^15.2.0` which got you version `15.2.9`, since you used `^` which translates to the latest minor version in the form of `15.2.X`.

When you run `npm install @ngx-translate/core` without specifying a version, it takes the latest version, which is `15.0.0`. This version has a dependency of `@angular/common@">=16.0.0"` which isn't compatible with the version you're using in your project (`15.2.9`).

You have two options to resolve the matter:

1. Upgrade the version of `@angular/common`. This will probably be quite complicated because you'll have to update other packages as well since it's one of the main packages of Angular.
2. **[Recommended]** Select a previous version of `@ngx-translate/core` that will have a dependency your project can fulfill as it is now. Try the following: `npm install @ngx-translate/core "~14.0.0"`. This will get you the latest sub-version of `@ngx-translate/core` in the `14.X.X` version.